# How to make clickable line in JQuery Flot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using flot to make line charts. One of the functionality I am trying to implement is highting the line (including points on the line and its corresponding legend), if the user clicks on the line, cancel the highlighting if the user clicks anywhere else on the chart.

Tried 'plotclick' event, but it requires clicking on points. I need the ability to get the series when clicking on the line as well.

Hopefully, there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually search for the nearest point on the line and then calculate the distance with something like this:

```
$('#placeholder').on('plotclick', function(event, pos, item) {
    $('#output').empty();
    if (item) { // clicked on point
        $('#output').text('series: ' + item.series.label + ' - datapoint: ' + item.dataIndex);
        return;
    }
    else { // search for line
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i-1][0] <= pos.x && pos.x < data[i][0]) {
                var lineX = (pos.x - data[i-1][0]) / (data[i][0] - data[i-1][0]);
                var lineY = data[i-1][1] + lineX * (data[i][1] - data[i-1][1]);
                if (Math.abs(pos.y - lineY) < maxDistance) {
                    $('#output').html('between datapoints ' + (i-1) + ' and ' + i + '<br />'
                        + 'distance from line: ' + Math.abs(pos.y - lineY).toFixed(3));
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/np45pdzz/) for a full example. If you have multiple data series you can search for the nearest point on each line and then calculate the nearest line.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question. I am also using the spline plugin to draw smooth lines. I can see your algorithm works for straight lines. How would you do the same thing for smooth lines?

Comment: After drawing the smoothed lines you can get the smoothed data by using `plot.getData()` (if you saved your Flot plot-object to a variable named plot). Then use that smoothed data instead of the original data. Something similar is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35292404/2610249) (using the animator plugin on smoothed data).